# Export Google Analytics UTM measures to spreadsheet

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My team is creating several UTM links and we would like to achieve better understanding of our campaigns through a google spreadsheet.

Our spreadsheet lets us prepare easily new UTM links, but we would also like to gather data related to the activity of those UTM links, that we would otherwise have to get through google analytics and selecting the right parameters

Is it possible to add an extra column(s) that would automatically retrieve such information from Google Analytics ? Maybe a script that we can run once in a while, and that would pull the number of clicks GA has registered for every UTM link ?

Online I have found some scripts to assist UTM link generation, but nothing about actually retrieving/exporting the results automatically to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use the [Google Analytics Spreadsheets Add-On](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) and filter (or segment) by your campaign (utm) information. You can configure multiple independent reports for different campaigns and set a trigger to have it updated automatically in regular intervals.

Comment: I wanted to have custom fields in the spreadsheet, in addition to the felds related to UTM parameters. Is it compatible with that ?

Comment: Well it's a spreadsheet - when in doubt you can do a formula with a vlookup on the finished report and insert your metrics into the sheet with your custom fields.